# SSO not working with AM-SESSION-DESTROYED error

Tags: single-sign-on, openam, opendj, forgerock

We configured Single Sign On for our applications using Forgerock. SSO configuration is like OpenDJ as the user store of OpenAM. It was working fine for  5-6 Months without any issues. Now a days application users report that user login is not working. User login is start working, When I restart the tomcat service running for OpenAM. When I am checking the openAM Log, I found the following error message. Some how AM-SESSION-DESTROYED.

*"26341d5b-b176-47d8-9ee9-725bbf93e36e-2418","2018-02-01T04:38:06.000Z","**AM-SESSION-DESTROYED**","26341d5b-b176-47d8-9ee9-725bbf93e36e-2195",,"[""86489d968cd61d3001""]","id=dsameuser,ou=user,dc=ds,dc=dddd,dc=com","86489d968cd61d3001","DELETE",,,,,"Session",*

When I am restarting the tomcat I got the following success log with each user logins

*"02537965-811e-456b-badc-8fb69ab5ef15-4499","2018-02-01T05:51:35.653Z","**AM-SESSION-CREATED**","02537965-811e-456b-badc-8fb69ab5ef15-4495","id=amadmin,ou=user,dc=ds,dc=dddd,dc=com","[""dddd832ef0aecd0401""]","id=dsameuser,ou=user,dc=ds,dc=dddd,dc=com","dddd832ef0aecd0401","CREATE",,,,,"Session","/"*

Comment: I am running both OpenAM and OpenDJ are in same server

Comment: You should look at the debug logs stored under the debug folder instead of the audit logs. Also how does the problem manifest itself for the end-users?

Comment: I saw some errors in the Sessions file inside the debug folder. Checking those. From end user side, their login is not works at that time